# Does the API allow access to document metadata on Evernote?

Tags: evernote

I have a smart pen that automatically uploads my notes to Evernote. My handwritten notes are OCR'ed and are searchable in Evernote (premium). Is there any way to programmatically access the digitalised version of my notes via Evernote's API? (I assume the digitalised text is added as meta content to the file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

Take a look at https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/image_recognition.php and https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceRecognition

It should help.

NB : The [Evernote API terms of service](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/api_license.php) prohibit you from simply using Evernote as a cloud OCR engine.

Comment: many thanks. I see this index is pretty raw, I guess I am going to try sending the resource to https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr.